# How can I reload files in /lib on every request?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, module

Rails loads controllers, helpers and models on each request.

My controllers have a bunch of modules which include methods for shared actions

Each time I change the modules, I have to restart Rails for the changes in the actions to take effect

Any idea how I can tell rails to reload these modules too?

---

### Update:

My directory structure is like so:

```
  app/
    controllers/
      app1/
        users_controller.rb
      app2/
        users_controller.rb

  lib/
    templates/
      controllers/
        users_controller_template.rb
```

Both App1::UsersController and App2::UsersController load UsersControllerTeplate like so:

```
# app/controllers/app1/users_controller.rb
class App1::UsersController < App1::ApplicationController
  require "templates/controllers/users_controller_template"
  include Templates::Controllers::UsersControllerTemplate
end

# templates/controllers/users_controller_template.rb
module Templates::Controllers::UsersControllerTemplate

  def self.included(base)
    base.class_eval do
      # some class macros called here
    end
  end
  
  # actions defined here
  def index
  end

end
```

In application.rb I've added:

```
config.autoload_paths += %W{ #{config.root}/lib/templates/ }
```

But I still have to reload the server to see changes made in users_controller_template.rb

Any ideas?

Comment: I think shotgun is the solution: https://github.com/rtomayko/shotgun

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add them to your `autoload_paths` in your application.rb file and they will be re-loaded automatically along with the models and controllers.

```
config.autoload_paths << "#{config.root}/lib"
```

Comment: I've added:    config.autoload_paths += %W( #{config.root}/lib/templates/controllers )

My controllers load modules from within /lib/templates/controllers

This still doesn't seem to reload on each request? - any ideas?

Comment: This might have to do with your class/module definition. For rails to autoload the file structure must match the module/class nesting. For instance `lib/templates/controllers/my_class.rb` should define `Templates::Controllers::MyClass`. Also I don't believe you need to explicitly add the nested path to get the autoload to work.

Comment: Does my original post not work? It should - Rails is recursive in searching the autoload paths. I would recommend removing the `config.autoload_paths += %W{ #{config.root}/lib/templates/ }` line entirely. Also there is no need to require the file in your controller since it's part of the autoload_paths. You should remove the require line entirely.

Comment: I've removed the 'require' - still reloads - thanks!

It's not autoloading the modules though - even with only "#{config.root}/lib" in my autoload_paths.

Comment: I can't reproduce your error at this point. I would ensure that `lib` is not in your `autoload_once_paths`, but other than that your code seems correct. I would try creating a new rails app with a nested lib directory in your autoload_paths to verify that this works.

Answer (score 2):

In `config/application.rb`:

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)
config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/lib/**/"]
```

This will reload any Ruby files in your lib folder as well as any Ruby files within subdirectories of lib.